# ~/.bash_profile not source from symlinked login shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, profile

If I call

```
bash --login
```

Then ~/.bash_profile is called. This seems as it should.

I also have /bin/sh symlinked to bash

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun 22  2017 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Calling

```
/bin/sh --login
```

Does not result in ~/.bash_profile being sourced. Instead ~/.profile gets sourced which may not include relevant bash specific things.

Is this how It should be? Is there a way to ensure ~/.bash_profile is called?

I'm running on Centos 6, with Bash 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

When bash is invoked as sh, it attempts to act as if it were a standard POSIX shell, so of course it doesn't source `~/.bash_profile`.  This is all documented; see `man bash`.  If you want automatic sourcing of `~/.bash_profile`, invoke it as bash.